# Catching form submit result

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a page which calls an external library, this library adds a payment form:

```
<form name="multipay_form" onsubmit="private_payment_send(); return false;">
     ....
</form>
```

I can not change any code here. I need to call a function after form is submitted. What I have done is:

```
jQuery('form[name="multipay_form"]').on('submit', function() {
    alert("myfunction");
});
```

Which works ok, but there is one exception, the method "private_payment_send()", does form validation, I need to know if their function returned true or false, to be able to trigger my function or not.

Is this possible?. I want to avoid doing the validation again on my end, since if they add new field or any new rule I would have to do the same on my code, which is not optimal. Any ideas?

Is there a way to unattach the function from the form through javascript?, in that way I can call private_payment_send() from my function

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it, unless the `private_payment_send()` function sets a global variable that indicates whether it was valid or not.

Comment: You can pass a callback and that callback function invokes when validation is true private_payment_send(yourfunction)

Comment: @AnkitPandey thanks for your answer, I can not modify private_payment_send()

Comment: Is there a way to unattach the function from the form through javascript?, in that way I can call private_payment_send() from my function

Comment: I added an answer showing how to remove the function from the onsubmit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form name="multipay_form" onsubmit="private_payment_send(); return false;">
     <button type="submit">test</button>
</form>

 document.getElementsByName("multipay_form")[0].setAttribute('onsubmit','');
```

This will make it so the onsubmit is removed from the form without touching the HTML

Answer (score 1):

Try to use done() function in Jquery

```
.done(function( n ) {
    $( "p" ).append( n + " we're done." );
  });
```

Following is Jquery documentation

https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Comment: I did not find a way to apply it but it looked an interesting option for other cases

Comment: Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger your function only when the called function, here "private_payment_send" has returned true. This can be done like this

```
<form name="multipay_form" onsubmit="if (private_payment_send()) { alert("myFunction") }; return false;">
    ...
</form>
```

If you only want to use the jQuery part, you can completely remove the onSubmit attribute and only assign the submit handler using jQuery

```
jQuery('form[name="multipay_form"]').on('submit', function() {
    if (private_payment_send())
        alert("myfunction");

    return false;
});
```

Comment: He said he can't change the HTML.

Comment: Is there a way to unattach the function from the form through javascript?, in that way I can call private_payment_send() from my function